# Checked radio button persistence when value changed by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a workaround to this, so I'm more just curious than actually needing a solution.

---

I have a form with client side validation that, if validation passes:

1. Hides the form (with user input values intact)
2. Builds and shows an unordered list *in the same page* summarising what will be submitted
3. Within the summary list, provides the user the option to make changes if they wish to do so before finally submitting the form.

One of the fields is a radio button group, where each option has a value which is a combination of 2 data when JavaScript is off:

```
<input type="radio" name="date" value="{productCode}: {DD Mmm YYYY}">
```

When JavaScript is present, the value is split:

```
<input type="hidden" name="product-code" value="{productCode}">
<input type="radio" name="date" value="{DD Mmm YYYY}">
```

This split happens when the user proceeds past validation to the summary page state.

**A.** If they go on directly to submit the form, their date selection **persists** and all works fine.

**B.** But (in Chrome 47 at least) when the user gets to the summary state *and then makes changes* (to other fields), their date selection is **lost** on form submission, and so server side validation reports an error.

This happens even though, when the user chooses to makes changes:

- The date selected is not messed with – the form is merely shown again and the summary `ul` cleared of text and hidden
- The selected radio button still shows as selected

Here's the jQuery function called when the user decides to make changes:

```
function changeBooking() {
    // assume changes will be made so clear summary values
    $('#summary li[id^="summary-"] > [data-value]').text('');

    // switch views from summary back to booking form
    $('#summary, #do-booking').hide();      
    $('#book fieldset.panel, #do-summary').show();
    $('#book').scrollView(20);
}
```

And it still happens when JavaScript adds an explicit `checked` attribute to the selected date *after* splitting the date and code values.

So I infer there is some sort of internal browser event happening that I can't figure.

I'd be grateful if someone can suggest why there should be a difference in radio button selection persistence between cases A and B at all.

---

For what it's worth, my workaround is to have the initial values of the radio group be presented in `name="code-date"`, a field value that never gets messed with. And the JavaScript splits the value into 2 hidden fields – `name="product-code"` and `name="date"` – which are initially blank and remain so when JavaScript is off.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the problem in a snippet or a fiddle?

Comment: Thanks Jamie. After posting I figured that would be the thing to do. Will come back and do that when I can.